Kubeflow 2.2 pipeline error: No existing KFP Config file found
I am trying to use the kubeflow v2 following the document below but but I am not able to run this succesfully. Below is my code snippet, Could you please let me know if something wrong.
https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/components/containerized-python-components/#1-source-code-setup
kfp                       2.7.0
kfp-kubernetes            1.2.0
kfp-pipeline-spec         0.3.0
kfp-server-api            2.0.5

kfp component build src/ --component-filepattern my_component.py

~/Doc/S/d/s/python-containerized ❯ tree                                  
.
├── kpf-test.ipynb
├── kubeflow-demo.yaml
└── src
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── my_component.cpython-312.pyc
    ├── component_metadata
    │   └── dataset_download.yaml
    ├── kfp_config.ini
    ├── my_component.py
    └── runtime-requirements.txt

#my_component.py
from kfp import dsl

@dsl.component(base_image='python:3.10',
               target_image='mohitverma1688/my-component:v0.4',
               packages_to_install=['pathlib','boto3','requests','kfp-kubernetes'])



def dataset_download(url: str, base_path:str, input_bucket:str):

    import os
    import requests
    import zipfile
    from pathlib import Path
    import argparse
    import boto3
    from botocore.client import Config
    
    s3 = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        endpoint_url="http://minio-service.kubeflow:9000",
        aws_access_key_id="minio",
        aws_secret_access_key="minio123",
        config=Config(signature_version="s3v4"),
    )
    # Create export bucket if it does not yet exist
    response = s3.list_buckets()
    input_bucket_exists = False
    for bucket in response["Buckets"]:
        if bucket["Name"] == input_bucket:
            input_bucket_exists = True
            
    if not input_bucket_exists:
        s3.create_bucket(ACL="public-read-write", Bucket=input_bucket)


    # Save zip files to S3 import_bucket
    data_path = Path(base_path)
    
    if data_path.is_dir():
      print(f"{data_path} directory exists.")
    else:
      print(f"Did not find {data_path} directory, creating one...")
      data_path.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)


    # Download pizza , steak and sushi data
    with open(f"{data_path}/data.zip", "wb") as f:
        request = requests.get(f"{url}")
        print(f"Downloading data from {url}...")
        f.write(request.content)
        for root, dir, files in os.walk(data_path):
            for filename in files:
                local_path = os.path.join(root,filename)
                s3.upload_file(
                   local_path,
                   input_bucket,
                   "data.zip",
                   ExtraArgs={"ACL": "public-read"},
                 )

 
    with zipfile.ZipFile(data_path/"data.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
      print("Unzipping data...")
      zip_ref.extractall(data_path)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        download(url, base_path, input_bucket)

#%%writefile pipeline.py

import src.my_component

BASE_PATH="/data"
URL="https://github.com/mrdbourke/pytorch-deep-learning/raw/main/data/pizza_steak_sushi.zip"
INPUT_BUCKET="datanewbucket"

@dsl.pipeline(name='CNN-TinyVG-Demo',
              description='This pipeline is a demo for training,evaluating and deploying Convutional Neural network',
              display_name='Kubeflow-MlFLow-Demo')



def kubeflow_pipeline(base_path: str = BASE_PATH,
                     url:str = URL,
                     input_bucket:str = INPUT_BUCKET):
    pvc1 = kubernetes.CreatePVC(
        # can also use pvc_name instead of pvc_name_suffix to use a pre-existing PVC
        pvc_name='kubeflow-pvc3',
        access_modes=['ReadWriteOnce'],
        size='500Mi',
        storage_class_name='standard',
    )
    task1 = dataset_download(base_path=base_path,
                            url=url,
                            input_bucket=input_bucket)
    task1.set_caching_options(False)
    kubernetes.mount_pvc(
        task1,
        pvc_name=pvc1.outputs['name'],
        mount_path='/data',
    )

compiler.Compiler().compile(kubeflow_pipeline, 'kubeflow-demo.yaml')

from kfp.client import Client

client = Client(host='http://localhost:8002')
run = client.create_run_from_pipeline_package(
    'kubeflow-demo.yaml',
     )

0524 12:18:56.775872      30 cache.go:116] Connecting to cache endpoint 10.96.39.24:8887
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: 
https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
[KFP Executor 2024-05-24 12:19:19,641 INFO]: --component_module_path is not specified. Looking for component `dataset_download` in config file `kfp_config.ini` instead
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kfp/dsl/kfp_config.py:69: UserWarning: No existing KFP Config file found
  warnings.warn('No existing KFP Config file found')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kfp/dsl/executor_main.py", line 109, in <module>
    executor_main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kfp/dsl/executor_main.py", line 75, in executor_main
    raise RuntimeError('No components found in `kfp_config.ini`')
RuntimeError: No components found in `kfp_config.ini`
I0524 12:19:19.748954      30 launcher_v2.go:151] publish success.
F0524 12:19:19.749580      30 main.go:49] failed to execute component: exit status 1
time="2024-05-24T12:19:20.313Z" level=info msg="sub-process exited" argo=true error="<nil>"
Error: exit status 1
time="2024-05-24T12:19:20.602Z" level=info msg="sub-process exited" argo=true error="<nil>"
Error: exit status 1


I am wondering if I have understood the document or not. Is this right way to run? I am using jupyter notebook.

I found the error in my configuration. I have to remove below code
if __name__ == "__main__":
        download(url, base_path, input_bucket)

